# Eclipse SWT Text field cursor jumps to start when deleting a space

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, textfield

In an application, we are using org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text. But we have encountered a bug which we dont know how to solve.

When editing text in the field, we have problem with the cursor. If a fill text "I dont know", and subsequently use backspace, and when we delete a space (" "), the cursor jumps to the start of text.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: please show your code, especially modify listener

Comment: If you've added any Listeners to the Text control, verify that none of them are moving the cursor.

Comment: What platform (macOS, Linux, Windows) is this? Show us an [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Yes problem was that someone add more listeners and trim text and than set into property where propertychangelistener set new trimmer value